# I know how to parse HTML I am trying to replace the goto command in php code

Tags: php, loops, web-scraping, goto

I am getting all kinds of errors with this code. I am trying to echo the category and subcategories of the www.forever21.com website with its respective url. So the output on the screen should be:

Category - Subcategory1 - Subcategory2 - Subcategory3 - url

I sort of get it to work if I comment the "while" commands and I take away the "goto" command.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
   $source = file_get_contents('http://www.forever21.com');

   $navigation = strpos($source, '<ul class="navigation">');
   $navigation_end = strpos($source, '</ul>', $navigation);

   $find_li_end = $navigation;

   while ($href < $navigation_end) {
   $find_li = strpos($source, '<li>', $find_li_end);
   $find_li_end = strpos($source, '</li>', $find_li);

   $cat_begin = strpos($source, 'class="dropdown-toggle">', $find_li);
   $cat_end = strpos($source, '</a>', $cat_begin);
   $category = substr($source, $cat_begin + 24, $cat_end - $cat_begin - 24);

   $title = $cat_end;
   $href_end = $cat_end;   
   while ($href < $find_li_end) {
again:
   $href = strpos($source, 'href="', $href_end);
   $href_end = strpos($source, '"', $href + 6);

   if ($title === false) {
    $title = $navigation_end;
    } 
    Else {
    $title = strpos($source, 'class="title"', $title);
    }

   if ($href > $title) {
    $subcat1_begin = strpos($source, '">', $title + 14);
    $subcat1_end = strpos($source, '<span', $subcat1_begin);
    $subcat1 = substr($source, $subcat1_begin + 2, $subcat1_end - $subcat1_begin - 2);
    $href_end = $subcat1_end;
    goto again;
    }

   $cat_url = substr($source, $href + 6, $href_end - $href - 6);

   if (strlen($cat_url) > 4) {

    echo ucwords(strtolower($category));
    echo " - ";
    echo ucwords(strtolower($subcat1));
    echo " - ";
    echo ucwords(strtolower($subcat2));
    echo " - ";
    echo ucwords(strtolower($subcat3));
    echo " - ";
    echo $cat_url;
    echo "<br>";

    }
   }
   }
?>
```

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/ XD

Comment: Thank you Diego ... 14 years with PHP and I've NEVER seen anyone use a `goto`.  Anyway ... this particular task is better suited to libraries like [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).  Have a look at [THIS ARTICLE](https://gist.github.com/anchetaWern/6150297) to get an idea of the techniques involved.